# how to use form_dropdown helper of codeigniter

Tags: forms, codeigniter, drop-down-menu

i am using ci helper form_dropdown for my form to get the required input type as textbox,radio button etc using dropdown menu. for the puropse i am using display_text and multiple_values in db where display_text stores textbox, radio button etc whereas in multiple values I store 0 or 1 depending on whether the input takes multiple values or not.e.g for textarea multiple_values = 0 and for radio button multiple_values = 1.now the problem is during the edit from the controller i am doing

```
$data['field_types'] = dropdown_data($field_types, 'display_text' , 'multiple_values');
```

when i send like this the saved value isn't selected,it just selects the first value of dropdown menu always but allows the selection of new value.from the controller when i do like

```
$data['field_types'] = dropdown_data($field_types, 'display_text');
```

the result is during edit the saved value is shown but it doesn't allow the change now.
i want both the earlier selected value to be displayed plus also able to change the value during edit.
where i am making the mistake. thanks in advance for any help/suggestions and your valuable time.

Answer (score 0):

First option:

In Controller:

```
$data['field_types']=array( 
                           '1' => 'First DropDownItem',
                           '2' => 'Second DropDownItem',
                           '3' => 'Third DropDownItem'
                           );

$data['field_types']['4']='New DropDownItem';
$data['field_types']['0']='New Default_DropDownItem';
```

In View:

```
<?=form_dropdown('field_types',$field_types,0); ?> // default value will be 'New Default DropDownItem'
```

Second option with database (rational way):

In Controller:

```
$data['field_types_from_model']=$this->my_Model->getFieldTypes();
```

In my_Model:

```
function getFieldTypes() {
  $Q = $this->db->get('table_with_field_types');
  return $Q->result_array();
}
```

If you are using the same DropDown List multiple times, I suggest you to use the Second option. This way you need to change your DropDown List once in your database table which will affect all usages.